# Unable to navigate to previous page using device back button (Backhandler)

Tags: android, react-native, navigation, hardware

I have 2 Screens, Screen A and Screen B. I am including Screen B in Screen A.
When I am in the Screen B, I am able to navigate back from the device back button to Screen A.

But when I go the Screen B and navigate back to Screen A, the device back button is not working in Screen A.

Screen A

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { View, Button, BackHandler } from 'react-native';
    import B from './B';

    export default class A extends Component { 
    
      state = {
         isB: false,
      }
    _onBack = () => {
    this.props.navigation.goBack();
    return true;
    }
    
    componentDidMount(){
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this._onBack)
    }
    
    ComponentWillUnmount(){
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this._onBack)
    }
    
    render(){
    <>
    {
       isB ?
         <B/>
       :
       <View>
         <Button onPress={() => this.setState({ isB: true})}>Edit</Button>
       </View>
    }
    </>
    }
  }
```

Screen B

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { View, BackHandler } from 'react-native';
    export default class B extends Component { 
    
    _onBack = () => {
    this.props.navigation.goBack();
    return true;
    }
    
    componentDidMount(){
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this._onBack)
    }
    
    ComponentWillUnmount(){
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this._onBack)
    }
    
    render(){
       <View>
       </View>
    }
  }
```

Comment: is your screen A, main page? i mean the one that is mounted first and you expect to close the app on back press?

Comment: No, its not main page @Amas

Answer (score 0):

This is from official docs:

> The event subscriptions are called in reverse order (i.e. the last
> registered subscription is called first).
>
> If one subscription returns true, then subscriptions registered earlier will not be called.
>
> If no subscription returns true or none are registered, it programmatically invokes the default back button functionality to exit
> the app.

So when you return `true` in `_onBack` , this will be the only callback that will be called in back button press.

you have to do what you want in this function, if you want to navigate back to the screen you were before`(you probably using a navigation library like react-navigation or router-flux)` put the proper code in this funtcion like below:

```
_onBack = () => {
    Actions.pop() // rn-router-flux
    navigation.goBack(); // rn-navigation
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Hey, I am using react-navigation-stack and tried your solution, but could not go back to previous page. Navigation is working for other screens. but if I include a page inside any page its not working.